# Checking table contents against actual values

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I am recently working with customer information spread across several databases, with no data dictionary, and little access to domain experts. There can be several tables with almost the same data, but different column names, some of which are heavily abbreviated. Some tables infrequently refreshed or not at all.

I have access to an application which shows the actual values. One of these is a binary (`Yes/No`) flag.

How many instances (samples) would I need to check, in order to have a high level of certainty that I am looking at the correct table and column?

Comment: If data model is unknown to you ("heavily abbreviated" column names), I'd say that - even if you check 100% instances, you can't be sure whether data you compared actually *should* be compared. Binary data EMPH (as a column name, meaning "employee is hungry (Y/N)" and EMPA ("employee is active (Y/N)") look similar, but really don't make sense when compared.

Comment: I feel to make sure you are looking at the right data you need to find one, look at the value, and then change the value in the table.  Is the change reflected in the app?

Comment: Do you have the resources to set up empty duplicates of the databases involved? Having full control of the inputs (and making these as simple as possible) makes it much easier to correlate the output. For example, set all columns to some known value, then change exactly one -- whatever changes is the column you're after. With sufficient sophistication (like leveraging accessibility APIs to observe the application) you can even automate this process, at least for the basic stuff of linking columns to their displayed values (understanding the data is another matter).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have write access to the application, but monitoring the changes on a particular value from day to day may work just as well. Thanks for the inspiration!